# Criar lista de ips válidos em php para uma tabela mysql

Tags: php, lista

Bom dia pessoal, estou precisando criar uma lista de ips válidos da minha rede. Eu tenho 15 subredes de classe A. Ou seja, minha rede é **10.5.5.0** até **10.5.20.255**. Tava pensando em algo como: `$IP 
for (i=1; i<255; i++) 
do $IP.$i` 
Porém, nessa lógica, eu só criaria ips da classe C. 
Esta lista seria inserida para uma tabela mysql.
Aguardo sugestões.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip = '10.5.';
for ($redeB=5; $redeB < 21 ; $redeB++) { 
    for ($redeC=1; $redeC < 255; $redeC++) { 
        echo $ip.$redeB.'.'.$redeC.'<br>';
    }
}
```

O primeiro for para contar a `rede B`, o segundo for para contar a `rede C`.
O primeiro for conta de `5 ~ 20`, dentro de for coloquei outro for para contar de `1 ~ 254`, a cada rede B o segundo for vai vai contar de `1 ~ 254`.

Comment: Muito obrigado Luis. Entendi a lógica. Mas como posso gerar isso para um _INSERT_ numa tabela mysql?

Comment: Utilizando PDO(recomendado):http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php
Ou mysqli: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php.